# PYTHON calculation of conversion coefficients for UBVRI filters to standard photometric system

Tags: python, star-cluster, standards

**First of all hello, I am new to this forum and I apologize in advance if I am wrong.** 
I am doing open cluster observations and as a result of these observations I am trying to find the conversion coefficients for UBVRI filters to the standard photometric system. I need to write a code in python using "curve fit" and error codes, but I am not very proficient.
The equations I need to use are in the photo. If you want to look at it additionally, you can look at the article written by Janes et al. **[Link](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-6256/145/1/7#aj450229r21)**
[image]

I made my observations of 17 standard fields selected from Landolt (2009) with the telescope. After downloading my fits images with information such as air mass (X), luminosities, etc., I registered them in a database. The atmospheric extinction and conversion coefficients to the standard photometric system and the nightly constants calculated in a previous project at the telescope we observed are given in the photo below.

[image: atmospheric]

I aim to find new coefficients by using the coefficients in the photo, the database I obtained by reducing the coefficients from the fits images and the luminosities of Landolt Standard Stars in the literature.

For example $$ v=V+\alpha_{bv}\ (B-V)+k_v\ X_v+C_{bv} $$ in this equation: I have the UBVRI luminosities and air masses from my standard field observations, so V , (B-V) and X are known. alpha_bv, k_v and C_bv will be taken from the table I provided and used in the curve fit. We can write them down by defining a p0. For example, if we define $$ \alpha_{bv}=-0.021 , k_b=0.238 , C_{bv} =-0.901 $$ in a p0 list, it can make our job easier when using curve_fit.

I want to call the database in python where I added the data I got with the reduction and after extracting my data, I want to calculate the same data and its errors with curve fit using the data given in the table above?

I would be very grateful if there is someone who can help me even briefly on this subject. **Thank you.**

Comment: We're going to need a little more information. What are the open cluster observations you are trying to transform, where did they come from (are they your own data or are you replicating another dataset/paper) and what else do you have ? $X$ in the above is the airmass and the $k_v$ etc are the extinction coefficients - fitting these normally needs observations of standard stars of known mags. over a range of airmass (inverse altitude basically; 1.0 is the zenith, 2 is 30deg altitude). If you can edit and add some details this will makes things easier

Comment: Thank you for the return. I have corrected my question again and added the new information.

Comment: I still don't see a question here.

Comment: Hi Rob, I think I asked my question clearly. If I need to ask again briefly, I want to find the new values of the above equations using curve_fit with a function.

Comment: @houst in the mean time, can you add a sentence that ends with a question mark that is an actual question to which proper Stack Exchange answers can be posted? *Thanks!*

Comment: @ProfRob I just got the notification again. I guess I didn't get a notification because I didn't tag you, so I'm commenting again. I'm sorry.

Comment: @astrosnapper I just got the notification again. I guess I didn't get a notification because I didn't tag you, so I'm commenting again. I'm sorry.

Comment: I still don't get it. You describe a procedure - "I want to... " (which souds fine) and then just end it with a question mark. Is the question - "does this procedure sound like the right thing to do"? Or what?

Comment: @ProfRob I cannot solve my work without using the equation given by Janes et al. I am trying to calculate the coefficients in nightly observations and I am trying to run this procedure in python and get output. I apologize my English is a bit bad.